# How to implement a generic cache manager in c#

Tags: c#, generics, locking

I'm trying to implement a generic cache manager, however I'm not sure how to go about doing the locking.

I have the following so far, however if I have two cache entries with the same return types then I'm guessing the same lock object would be used!

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
    static class TypeLock<T>
    {
        public static readonly object SyncLock = new object();
    }
    private readonly ICache _cache;
    public CacheManager(ICache cache)
    {
        if (cache == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cache");

        _cache = cache;
    }

    public TResult AddCache<TResult>(string cacheKey, Func<TResult> acquire, int cacheDurationInMinutes) where TResult : class
    {
        return AddCache(cacheKey, null, acquire, cacheDurationInMinutes);
    }

    public TResult AddCache<TResult>(string cacheKey, CacheDependency dependency, Func<TResult> acquire, int cacheDurationInMinutes) where TResult : class
    {
        var entry = acquire.Invoke();
        if (entry != null)
        {
            if (dependency != null)
                _cache.InsertWithDependency(cacheKey, entry, dependency, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheDurationInMinutes));
            else
                _cache.Insert(cacheKey, entry, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheDurationInMinutes));
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public TResult GetOrAddCache<TResult>(string cacheKey, Func<TResult> acquire, int cacheDurationInMinutes) where TResult : class
    {
        return GetOrAddCache(cacheKey, null, acquire, cacheDurationInMinutes);
    }

    public TResult GetOrAddCache<TResult>(string cacheKey, CacheDependency dependency, Func<TResult> acquire, int cacheDurationInMinutes) where TResult : class
    {
        var entry = _cache.GetItem(cacheKey) as TResult;

        if (entry == null)
        {
            lock (TypeLock<TResult>.SyncLock)
            {
                entry = _cache.GetItem(cacheKey) as TResult;
                if (entry == null)
                {
                    entry = acquire.Invoke();
                    if (entry != null)
                    {
                        if (dependency != null)
                            _cache.InsertWithDependency(cacheKey, entry, dependency,
                                                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheDurationInMinutes));
                        else
                            _cache.Insert(cacheKey, entry, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheDurationInMinutes));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return entry;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use something from System.Runtime.Caching namespace?

Comment: I'm building on top of SharePoint 2010, so unfortunately .net 3.5 framework.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: As it stands, the same lock object will be used for any cache entries with the same return type, whereas I want to only use the lock on the same cache entry

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this would use the same lock for all cache entries of the same type. To keep you actual caching method (memory, file, database...) independent of this cache manager, I suggest storing an extra sync object for each cache entry, so your cache entries will look for example like `Tuple<object, TResult>` instead of just `TResult`, where the `object` will be a `new object()` for each entry and will be used for locking.

Comment: Regarding your comment for my answer - Shame to me, you are right! This is a way how Jon Skeet made singleton [Fifth version - fully lazy instantiation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: Honza, would you be able to provide an example on how you would implement it with Tuple<object, TResult>?  Many thanks

Comment: My idea was that your `ICacheManager` interface would stay the same, but in its implementation (i.e. `CacheManager` class) you would use a modified `ICache` interface, which would expose not only [key, value] pairs, but also a sync object for each such pair.The `Tuple` version was just a quick idea, it would be better to create some sort of `CacheEntry` object which would contain `Value` and `SyncObject` properties. What would that mean in your code is that you can use `var entry = _cache.GetItem(cacheKey)` and then use `if(entry != null) lock (entry.SyncObject) { ... }`

Comment: @HonzaBreston And if the entry is null, what would I lock on?  At the moment the code only locks if there is no entry in the cache, so that two threads don't try and populate the cache at the same time.

Comment: You're right, in this case my idea is not helpful at all. Lightweight solution might be using for example `BlockingCollection<TCacheKey>` (or other thread-safe collection) to see what keys are being added to the cache. Then instead of locking, you can put the new key in this collection, add the corresponding entry to the cache, then remove the key from the collection.

Comment: I'll give it a go with a Synchronized Collection then, as I'm using .net 3.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should never lock in your caching code unless its really needed.
Use Concurrent dictionary if you don't want to use any well known cache.

I'd also say you probably should use the `System.Runtime.MemorCache` instead.

Or you use a solution which does abstract this for you, 
like my CacheManager https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should use lock, alos, why not use MemoryCache instead of ICache interface? Isn't memory cache generic enough?
Why did you force  cache time to be in minute, you should pass a timespan to your cache methods, I would be more generic.

I implemented [a version of a cache manager](http://www.sharefunction.com/Code/232) few month ago, but it was web oriented.